# How to set parameter's description with hybrid_command

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make bot discord bot using discord.py, and I wanna to add description on parameter.
How can I add it?

```
@bot.hybrid_command(name="meow", description="Give me food meow~")
async def meow(interaction: discord.Interaction, food: str):#food parameter should have description
#send food to this cat
```

Comment: Use the [app_commands.describe](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.describe) decorator.